# How to merge data in JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

Hi I have a JSON file containing the following data:

```
{
    "key": {
        "domain": "hello.com"
    },
    "data": {
        "array": [
            {
                "name": "non",
                "id": "869474210",
                "Code": "GHQ"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I merge the data so that "domain" is within "array", as below?

```
{
    "data": {
        "array": [
            {
                "domain": "hello.com"
                "name": "non",
                "id": "869474210",
                "Code": "GHQ"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: See [working with JSON data in Python](https://realpython.com/python-json/).

Comment: Can there be multiple elements in the array? Do you need the domain added to all of them?

Comment: If there can't be multiple elements, why is it an array? And if you don't want the domain added to all, which should it be added to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you've already parsed the data into a Python dictionary.

We can access the `domain` element and add that to the array. Then we can use `.pop("key")` to remove the `"key"` key in the dictionary.

```
old = {
    "key": {
        "domain": "hello.com"
    },
    "data": {
        "array": [
            {
                "name": "non",
                "id": "869474210",
                "Code": "GHQ"
            }
        ]
    }
}

new = old

# putting the domain into the array
new["data"]["array"][0]["domain"] = old["key"]["domain"]

# removing the "key" from the object
new.pop("key")
print(new)
#Output: {'data': {'array': [{'name': 'non', 'id': '869474210', 'Code': 'GHQ', 'domain': 'hello.com'}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. move the domain to the data then delete the key:

```
json['data']['array'][0]['domain'] = json['key']['domain']
del(json['key'])
```